# automatically input to terminal, from nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cordova, terminal, automation

This may sound rather crazy,
but I cannot find a solution to automate taking screenshots on a cordova application.

I know I can take and save a screenshot of the emulator using

```
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.png
```

in the terminal, my crazy question is.
Can I trigger these commands from a nodeJS automation script? or is this too far fetched and a terrible idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to execute terminal commands from node.js would be to use [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (error) {
     console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
     return;
   }
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

The built-in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) module in node.js provides many functions such child_process.spawn, child_process.exec, child_process.execFile which can be used to execute terminal commands or other script files (.sh, .bat).

Comment: you sir are a genius, thank you very much. I have been stuck on this problem for awhile!